# Queries comparing dateCreated don't work for test data created within a test transaction in Grails 3.3.10

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm, spock

We are migrating integration tests from our Grails 2.3.11 app to Grails 3.3.10. GORM version 6.1.12.

I am having issues with two tests in particular. Both of these issues are related to querying dates in test data set up within the test transaction, specifically comparing the `dateCreated` of an object to a date generated within the service.

In the `User` domain object, this is the `dateCreated` field that is managed by Grails (or GORM?) usually.

In one case this is done in HQL

```
Date twoYearsAgo = new Date()
use(TimeCategory) {
  twoYearsAgo = twoYearsAgo - 2.years
}

User.executeQuery("""
  select id
  from User
  where dateCreated > :cutoff
""", [cutoff: twoYearsAgo])
```

The other is using criteria

```
Date aMonthAgo = new Date()
use(TimeCategory) {
  aMonthAgo = aMonthAgo - 1.month
}

User.createCriteria().list {
  le("dateCreated", aMonthAgo)
}
```

These are simplified from our actual code.

Both service queries seem to work fine within tests with data committed to the test database during our bootstrap.

The issue is that they don't seem to work with test data setup within the test transaction.

For example, that first query will return results with `dateCreated < cutoff`.

In the test I setup test data like such

```
User user = new User()
Date threeYearsAgo = new Date()
use(TimeCategory) {
  threeYearsAgo = threeYearsAgo - 2.years
}
user.dateCreated = threeYearsAgo
user.save(flush: true)
```

Then I call my service function

```
List<User> list = service.serviceFunction()
```

which returns the results of a query something like this

```
Date twoYearsAgo = new Date()
use(TimeCategory) {
  twoYearsAgo = twoYearsAgo - 2.years
}

return User.executeQuery("""
  select id
  from User
  where dateCreated > :cutoff
""", [cutoff: twoYearsAgo])
```

Then back in the test, this assertion fails

```
assert list[0].dateCreated > twoYearsAgo // this is false!
```

The domain object returned, upon inspection, has the correct date for `dateCreated` which is 3 years ago.

Again, this error occurs only for data created within the test transaction and not with data already committed to the test database.

It feels like maybe the format that the Date is in within the hibernate cache is different. But I don't know how to debug the hibernate cache.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you configured your test to use the Hibernate implementation or the `Map` based implementation (which is the default for unit tests)?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am not sure which I have set. Could you point me to the docs reference? Also this is an integration test

Comment: My question would only be relevant if the tests were unit tests.  I missed the comment in the question indicating that it is an integration test.  Sorry for the noise.